# Firebase auth timeout from express.js app under Docker

Tags: reactjs, firebase, docker, firebase-authentication

I have an express.js/react app using Firebase authentication and firestore. When testing locally and on heroku it worked fine without issue, however now I put it inside a docker container (due to using an old version of caddy-docker and I don't want to deal with upgrading/another reverse-proxy, I'm constrained to wrap my apps in containers). However now when I access my site, trying to login with firebase gives an auth-timeout error. I made sure to whitelist my domain in firebase auth, and the site is reachable, so I'm not sure what's causing this error. Are specific ports required to be opened for firebase, or is something special required for firebase under docker? Could it be UFW blocking requests from my container to firebase? My full code is available here: https://github.com/ROODAY/SMMRY-Client (although probably only `server.js` and `Dockerfile` are useful).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this by just running the following:

```
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
sudo ufw reload
```

It seemed that it was UFW preventing the container from connecting with Firebase, so I just allowed all outgoing traffic and voila!